# Finite Cover of the Set of Alpha Discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\,$ be a bounded function and $D=\bigcup D_\alpha$ be a measure zero set  where

$$D_\alpha :=\{x_0\in[a,b]: \omega_f(x_0)\geq \alpha,  \},\quad \alpha >0. $$
Setting $\alpha := \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$, 
it needs to be shown that there exists a finite collection of open intervals $\{G_1,G_2,...,G_N\}$ such that the collection covers $D_\alpha$ and has
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |G_i|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{4M}$$
where $|G_i|$ is the length of the interval $G_i$ and $M = \sup\{f(x): x\in [a,b]\}$.

Comment: What's $f$?  What's $M$?  Are the $x_m$ members of a sequence or something?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit this so all of those things are clear.

Comment: The definition of $D_{\alpha}$ still doesn't make sense; in the condition $|f(x_0)-f(x)| \geq \alpha$, what point is $x$?  Is it a fixed point or something?  And what's the union you're taking to get $D$, and how do you know it's measure $0$?

Comment: $D_\alpha$ is the set of all alpha discontinuities of the function $f$ on $[a,b]$ i.e. points where the oscillation of $f$ exceeds $\alpha$. Taking the union of these sets gives all the dicontinuities of $f$ which is known to be a meausre zero set.

Comment: The reason $f$ is known to have measure zero is because this is a step in proving one side of the Lebesgue criterion for integrability i.e. $D$ has measure zero $\implies$ $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Sorry again, I still may have not made a few things clear. Feel free to edit/ask me to clarify.

Comment: I expect that $D_\alpha$ is supposed to be $\{x_0\in[a,b]:\omega_f(x_0)\ge\alpha\}$, where $$\omega_f(x)\triangleq\limsup\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)-\liminf\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$ is the oscillation of $f$ at $x_0$. Your expression for $D_\alpha$ simply makes no sense as written.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'll edit that now.

Comment: Do you want $\{G_1, G_2, \ldots, G_N\}$ to be an open cover of $D$ or $D_{\alpha}$?